# Best way to pass a parameter when switching to another controller

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to pass a parameter when moving from one controller to another (parallel) one?

Thank you

Comment: angular `service/factory` is the best option to share data among multiple controllers

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "parallel controller"? The best way is usually to make that parameter part of the URL, just like in any other web app. If you want to go from a list controller to a detail controller, you set the URL to `/detail/<id>`

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Angular's `value` if sharing data across the app is all you need.
Since you want to change `value`'s data in controllers, make it an object and change its properties.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .value('data', {})
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, data) {
        data.someValue = '...';
    });
```

`value` itself is essentially a syntactic sugar for `factory`:

```
function value(name, val) { return factory(name, valueFn(val), false); }

function valueFn(value) {return function() {return value;};}
```